# Should I merge the part files in bigger file to reach the maximum block size

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I collected multiple tweets and stored them in hdfs.
I know have a lot of part file in my hdfs.
They are very small, like 0.5 Ko because only one tweets is stored in one file.
I would like to know if it's ok to let them like this, or if it is better to merge them into bigger file that would try to reach the maximum block size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The small file problem is quite an issue for the HDFS for many reasons.

- The Namenode maintains the file system structure in-memory. More files in this case means higher RAM requirements on you master machine.
- Small files are also bad for reading, as the network protocols are used for transferring the data. Your application will suffer from higher delays when establishing the connection for the individual nodes to prepare the splits for being processed (the same techniques are used in Web Applications for example, when the static image components are aggregated into the moderately size image file and further extracted with CSS).
- Small files also result in lower I/O throughput, since whenever you are storing the larger file, the underlying disk placement algorithms have higher probability of placing the data on the adjacent disk segments, enabling the sequential extraction of the information.
- Each of the stored blocks creates a meta-data files, which stored the checksums used for data integrity checks. The meta-data file size is about 1Megabyte. In your case it will mean that your storage persists more meta-data then the actual information.

There might be additional problems with the small files which depend on other components integrated into your infrastructure.

Long story short: it is **not** a good idea to store one tweet in an individual file. Try looking for specific data ingestion tools (like Kafka for example), so you rather write already pre-processed large files into your system.